# How to substitute all commas to dots except the ones within special functions?

Tags: regex, string, vim, substitution

I'm trying to find a regex which substitutes all commas to dots, except the ones within special functions like `pow()`, `log()`, `sqrt()`, `max()` etc.

I tried this without succes:

```
let string = substitute(string, '\(pow([0-9.]\+\|log([0-9.]\+\|max([0-9.]\+\|\)\@<!\zs,\ze', '\.', 'g')
```

This does p.e a substitute of commas in `max(x, y, z)` but also in other special functions.

I would like to find a general regex which does not substitute a comma at all within all special functions but does a substitute of all other comma's in the string.

Possible input text:

let string = `2*3,25 + pow(2,3) + (-2,5 + max(2.25, 40, -5.3)) + 2,51/4.3`

Comment: It would be great to see some example input and output text. Also this sounds like you might be converting between number formats e.g. `##,##` -> `##.##`. If this is a case you might be able to use this to your advantage: `:%s/,\(\d\{3}\)/\1/g`

Answer (score 1):

Vim's Regexes are not that powerful. What you want is to actually parse the text so you can count the parens so you can determine context. You will have to roll your own parser.

Your other option is to try and use some kind of trick to figure out which `,` to replace based on surroundings. You can get close with `s/\v,(\d+)/\1/g`. This looks for `,` with a digit directly afterwards. However this fails for your `pow()` expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
(\©<=\)),
```

try this.it uses positive lookbehind to check, preceded by ).

Comment: This doesn't substitute commas after `()`

Comment: @Remonn this exactly does that.can you show the input you are trying on.

Comment: Vim regex does not support `?<=`

Comment: Maybe you mean `\@<=` (search for `?< =` in `:help pattern`)

Comment: @vks vim supports lookbehind and lookaheads but not with `?<=`

Comment: `?<=` is perl regex isn't it?